# Can I use wxWidgets instead of Qt?

Tags: c++, user-interface, build, open-source

I have downloaded a github project (citra). It uses Qt for it's UI. Can I use wxWidgets to build it instead of Qt and can I build it without use of cmake and VS2017 but using Other IDEs.

Here is the tutorial on how to build: 
https://github.com/citra-emu/citra/wiki/Building-For-Windows

Comment: **See also [QT vs wxWidgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19352797/qt-vs-wxwidgets)** (where Qt wins, because `wxWidgets` users are forced to use Qt's GUI, through `wxQt` module, read linked post for details).

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: not easily.

Long answer: You need to find the equivalent of all the Qt classes and replaces with an equivalent in wxWidgets, which may or may not exist directly. This can take a long time, and you need to test that the changes are sound. It can take months.

Then you need to change the build system if you don't like CMake, which is less work, but still sometimes more than a day.

Comment: Ok Thanks for help and about IDE